# DKIM for "From" domain or MX domain?

Tags: email-server, spf, dkim, dmarc

My server is handling mail for several virtual users and domains. The SPF records of the domains state that only the MX server is allowed to send mail (`v=spf1 mx -all`) and this MX server is a generic domain, so `example.org` and `example.com` have `mail.example.net` as MX. If I also want to implement DKIM, does each virtual domain needs its key in DNS and each outgoing mail must be signed using the domain's key, or does only the MX need a DKIM key and all outgoing messages, regardless which domain the `From` header states, is signed using the MX domain key?

Edit: Just to clarify, mails sent are `From: bob@example.org`, `From: alice@example.com` but are all sent via the server `mail.example.net`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure DKIM for a domain, not for an MX. Therefore, every domain must have a record for the selector, corresponding to the DKIM signature.

> [RFC 6376, 3.6.2.1.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.1)  Namespace
>
> All DKIM keys are stored in a subdomain named `_domainkey`.  Given
> a    DKIM-Signature field with a `d=` tag of `example.com` and an `s=`
> tag of `foo.bar`, the DNS query will be for
> `foo.bar._domainkey.example.com`.